Update Mac to point to Ruby Version 3.3.6
I have been losing my mind on this for quite a while. I have Macbook with Sequoia 15.1.1.
I installed Ruby with Homebrew.
When I enter ruby -v it shows the version that comes with Mac 2.6.10.
When I run brew list ruby it lists the files in /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.6/
How do I make 3.3.6 my default ruby when i enter ruby -v?

better use rbenv or rvm or anything similar

By default, Homebrew doesn't "replace" binaries that also come with your system. If you want to use the Homebrew Ruby, you have to add the path to its binary to your PATH yourself, see Installing Ruby with Homebrew
